How to send data returned from a function to client in Django in real time without the client need to refresh?
I am writing a program to retrieve data and display it in a Django template. I have a function called match_algo() that takes a long time to run. I want to initially show 'Loading...........' on the page, and once the function completes and returns the result, I want to display the retrieved content on the page.
This is the view I tried first:
def redirected_page(request):
    data = match_algo()
    
    context = {
        'data' : json.dumps(data),
        'test' : 'test'
    }
    
    return render(request , 'redirected_page.html' , context )


After some research, I found that WebSockets might help with this, but I'm still not sure if it's the solution I need.
This is my consumer.py:
class LoadingConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

       
        # Send "loading..." message when the connection is established
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': 'loading...',
            "status" : False
        }))

        data = match_algo()

        # Send "loading completed" message after processing is done
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': "loaded",
            "status" : True,
            # "matches" : data
        }))

        # Close the connection after sending the final message
        await self.close()

For testing purpose I commented this line
data = match_algo()
then added time.sleep(5).
This actually works. But when I run with match_algo after few seconds, the websockets disconnects. But the function match_algo works. Since the websocket connection is closing. I can't get the result nor can I display it.
Is there any way to fix this? Or any better method??
redirect.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Therapist Details</title>
    <style>
        table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        th {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        body {
            margin : 80px 150px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Therapist Details</h1>
    <div id="therapist-table-container">
        Matching Therapist suitable for you. Please wait.
    </div>
    
    <script>
        const loadingMessage = document.getElementById('loadingMessage');
        const socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/loading/');

        socket.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log('WebSocket opened with code:', event.code);
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(data.message)
            console.log(data.matches)
            
            if (data.status) {
                const tableHTML = `
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Specialty</th>
                      <th>Experience</th>
                      <th>Contact</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>John Doe</td>
                      <td>Clinical Psychology</td>
                      <td>10 years</td>
                      <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Jane Smith</td>
                      <td>Marriage and Family Therapy</td>
                      <td>8 years</td>
                      <td>janesmith@example.com</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Michael Johnson</td>
                      <td>Child and Adolescent Therapy</td>
                      <td>12 years</td>
                      <td>michaeljohnson@example.com</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                `;
        
                // Add the table to the DOM
                const tableContainer = document.getElementById('therapist-table-container');
                tableContainer.innerHTML = tableHTML;
              } else {
                // Hide the table if data.status is false
                const tableContainer = document.getElementById('therapist-table-container');
                tableContainer.innerHTML = 'Matching Therapist suitable for you. Please wait.';
              }
        };

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
            console.log('WebSocket closed with code:', event.code);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Thanks for your time

Yes thats possible with websockets. Yet the question is, whether your problem is worth the websocket setup. websockets are meant for bidi communication, where your server/client can interact w'o creating a new connection every time. But this comes to a price - the websocket has to be kept open for every client. If your algo takes a long time or even has a roughly pre determined runtime, you can get a much less resource heavy solution by doing polling (with predetermined runtime down to just asking once more).

Since your match_algo() function is running on the server, my comment won't help with showing a "Loading...." that actually indicates how much time is left, however, you can use JavaScript fetch to return the result from the server to the client without requiring the client to refresh the page.  Or, if you do have a way to measure your function's progress, you can use fetch() to update the progress every interval of time until the result is finally returned.

Websocket is a good way.
Javascript Websocket
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket
Python Websocket
https://pypi.org/project/websockets/
Send / Recive, any data in real time without any refresh, you can use Javascript like (document.getelement...) and change html data on recive any value.

You can do one of the following.

Use Celery for Background Tasks :- Celery is a system that implements and executes long-running tasks asynchronously and efficiently. It is compatible with Django and allows running match_algo() in the background while simultaneously notifying the client through WebSockets when the task is completed.

Django Channels with WebSockets: Using Django channels, you can manage WebSocket connections relatively comfortably. For instance, the page can be "busy" and display a "Loading..." text while match_algo() is being processed, then refresh when the processing is over.

AJAX Polling as an Alternative: Polling could be done instead of web sockets by periodically asking the server if the task has been completed using AJAX. Although it is less effective than WebSockets, it is easier to implement since it does not always need a connection open.

Django's Background Tasks: In most simple cases, when managing Djangos django-background-tasks, it is provided for creating background processes without the stickiness of fully fledged application Queues like Celery


You can read more on these methods to decide the best method for your usecase.

Yes celery is the most versatile way to offload work from your request-response django processes and def. the way to go if you have a lot async work to do. Still as a dropin' for a single async job it feels a bit overbloated. As a simple dropin' I often just create a custom django management command and call that in its own process.

For partial page reload(show data without reloading), you may use Django HTMX.
Installation guide for django HTMX:- https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
Docs for Django HTMX:- https://htmx.org/docs/
